# R - Disaggregate coverage area data based on a ranking preference

Tags: r, ranking, area

I have 4G mobile coverage at the Local Authority level in the UK, as a percentage of geographical area covered (for approximately 200 areas). I want to disaggregate this data so I can work with roughly 9000 lower-level postcode sector.

The most appropriate way for me to do this, is to allocate 4G geographic coverage to the most densely populated areas first, as this would best represent how mobile operators would invest in the market. The least populated areas would end up with no coverage. I'm struggling with how I do this in R, however.

I have a data frame that looks like this for the postcode sector data (I've used hypothetical data here):

```
Name      pcd.sect  pop    area pop.dens  rank  
Cambridge   1      5546    0.6   8341      1     
Cambridge   2      7153    1.1   5970      2     
Cambridge   3      5621    2.3   5289      3     
Cambridge   4      10403   4.3   4361      4     
Cambridge   5      14796   4.2   3495      5     
...
```

I then took the aggregate local authority data and put it on each row (adding the three right columns):

```
Name      pcd.sect  pop    area pop.dens  rank  LA.4G  LA.area   LA.4G(km2)
Cambridge   1      5546    0.6   8341      1     58     140        82
Cambridge   2      7153    1.1   5970      2     58     140        82  
Cambridge   3      5621    2.3   5289      3     58     140        82
Cambridge   4      10403   4.3   4361      4     58     140        82
Cambridge   5      14796   4.2   3495      5     58     140        82  
...
```

I had to shorten the headings, so let me just explain them in more detail:

- Name - Local Authority name
- pcd.sector - postcode sector (so the lower level unit)
- pop - the population in the postcode sector
- area - surface area of the postcode sector in km2
- pop.dens - is the population density of the postcode sector in persons per km2
- rank - rank of the postcode sector based on population density within each local authority
- LA.4G - % coverage of the local authority with 4G
- LA.area - the sum of the area column for each local authority
- LA.4G(km2) - the number of km2 with 4G coverage within each local authority

Taking Cambridge as a hypothetical example, there is 58% 4G coverage across the whole Local Authority. I then want to disaggregate this number to achieve 4G coverage for the individual postcode sectors.

Ideally the data would end up looking like this, with an extra column for the postcode sector coverage:

```
Name      pcd.sect  ...     pcd.sector.coverage (%)
Cambridge   1       ...         100
Cambridge   2       ...         100
Cambridge   3       ...         100
Cambridge   4       ...         34
Cambridge   5       ...         0
...        ...      ...         ...
```

How do I get R to allocate this 82km2 (58% geographical coverage) out to the postcode sectors in a new column, based on the area column, but then stopping once it hits the maximum coverage level of 82km2 (58% geographical coverage)?

Comment: Why is sector 4 and 5 not 100%? They have both 82km2.

Comment: LA.4G, LA.area and LA.4G(km2) are all at the local authority level, I've just put them on each row for simplicity. The numbers used here are illustrative, but the structure is correct.

Comment: please then edit your answer and include the calculation of the `pcd.sector.coverage`. I can't figure it out, but your problem could be solved using a `ifelse()` statement.

Comment: Hi Jimbou, I have now edited the answer to make it clearer which data are for the lower and upper level units. Thanks for the suggestion on 'ifelse()'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is how I interpret this question.  Correct me if this is not what you meant.
Suppose you have the following data.

```
dat <- data.frame(
  Name = "A", pcd.sector = 1:5,
  area = c(2, 3, 1, 5, 3), 
  areaSum = 14, LA.4G = 8
)
dat

#  Name pcd.sector area areaSum LA.4G
#1    A          1    2      14     8
#2    A          2    3      14     8
#3    A          3    1      14     8
#4    A          4    5      14     8
#5    A          5    3      14     8
```

You have five sectors, with various areas.  Although the areas sum up to 14, there are only 8 covered by 4G.  You want to allocate the areas from the sectors 1 through 5.

The following code does this job.  I used `cumsum` function to compute the cumulative sum of areas from the top sector, which is capped by the 4G coverage limit.  Allocated area can be computed by `diff` function, which takes the one-step difference of a vector.  The sector 1 through 3 gets 100% coverage, which sum up to 6 areas, hence only 2 remains.  Although sector 4 has 5 area, it can only enjoy 2, or 40%.  This uses up the areas and nothing is left for the sector 5.

```
dat$area_allocated <- diff(c(0, pmin(cumsum(dat$area), dat$LA.4G)))
dat$area_coverage  <- dat$area_allocated / dat$area * 100
dat

#   Name pcd.sector area areaSum LA.4G area_allocated area_coverage
# 1    A          1    2      14     8              2           100
# 2    A          2    3      14     8              3           100
# 3    A          3    1      14     8              1           100
# 4    A          4    5      14     8              2            40
# 5    A          5    3      14     8              0             0
```

If you have a lot of areas, then you may want to use `dplyr::group_by` function.

```
dat <- rbind(
  data.frame(
    Name = "A", pcd.sector = 1:5,
    area = c(2, 3, 1, 5, 3), 
    areaSum = 14, LA.4G = 8
  ),
  data.frame(
    Name = "B", pcd.sector = 1:3,
    area = c(4, 3, 2), 
    areaSum = 9, LA.4G = 5
  )
)

library(dplyr)
dat <- dat %>% group_by(Name) %>% 
  mutate(area_allocated = diff(c(0, pmin(cumsum(area), LA.4G)))) %>%
  mutate(area_coverage = area_allocated / area * 100)
dat

#     Name pcd.sector  area areaSum LA.4G area_allocated area_coverage
#   <fctr>      <int> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>          <dbl>         <dbl>
# 1      A          1     2      14     8              2     100.00000
# 2      A          2     3      14     8              3     100.00000
# 3      A          3     1      14     8              1     100.00000
# 4      A          4     5      14     8              2      40.00000
# 5      A          5     3      14     8              0       0.00000
# 6      B          1     4       9     5              4     100.00000
# 7      B          2     3       9     5              1      33.33333
# 8      B          3     2       9     5              0       0.00000
```

Comment: That has worked Kota Mori, except I want to allocate the coverage to the areas with the highest population density first. Can you help me take the rank variable outlined in the question into account please?

Comment: After I sorted the data based on rank variable, followed by the LA name, I got this working. Thanks, that's exactly what I needed!